# Cron drupal 8 for my module?

Tags: 8, cron

I am doing a module in drupal 8, I would like to know how to execute a function automatically every month. I think it's done with Cron, but I only get to do it every week. as I edit it from my function.

Comment: please revise your question it is not clear what you want to do ...

Answer (score 12):

A modified example from cron_example module. This doesn't concern the interval the cron tasks are set in cron.

This is important, as you will probably set another cron tasks sooner or latter with different interval requirements. Also, many system tasks require more frequent cron runs.

```
function cron_example_cron() {
  $interval = 30*24*60*60; // Approx a month of interval

  // We usually don't want to act every time cron runs (which could be every
  // minute) so keep a time for the next run in the site state.
  $next_execution = \Drupal::state()->get('cron_example.next_execution');
  $next_execution = !empty($next_execution) ? $next_execution : 0;
  if (REQUEST_TIME >= $next_execution) {
    // This is a silly example of a cron job.
    // It just makes it obvious that the job has run without
    // making any changes to your database.
    \Drupal::logger('cron_example')->notice('cron_example ran');
    if (\Drupal::state()->get('cron_example_show_status_message')) {
      drupal_set_message(t('cron_example executed at %time', ['%time' => date_iso8601(REQUEST_TIME)]));
      \Drupal::state()->set('cron_example_show_status_message', FALSE);
    }
    \Drupal::state()->set('cron_example.next_execution', REQUEST_TIME + $interval);
  }
}
```

Also, for more fine-tuned approach, you can use the [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron) module, which provides more fine-grained control for the cron jobs.

Comment: Followed this method to send a file to external server daily at 10.30 AM.But the cron didn't run as expected.Tried even without a scheduled time.No luck.
Based on the cron logs, the cron is not triggered at the scheduled time.Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: REQUEST_TIME [has been deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/node/2785211). Use `\Drupal::time()->getRequestTime()`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to run cron every month is by adding the following command to your crontab.

```
0 0 1 * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://CRON_URL
```

http://CRON_URL is replaced with a URL which is different for each Drupal version. For D8 it looks something like http://www.example.com/cron/. You can get this URL from Status report — Reports Administration > Reports > Status (/admin/reports/status)

For more info please visit https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/setting-up-cron-for-drupal/configuring-cron-jobs-using-the-cron-command

Comment: Ash, this comment is totally useless.  The OP is clearly asking about cron jobs in DRUPAL.  An answer for cron jobs in Linux does nothing to help.